# Re-enter Italy on Permesso di Soggiorno/Residence Permit receipts with Single Entry Visa

Tags: italy, long-stay-visas

I have been in Italy since November on Employment Visa D-Type. When I came here and applied for first issue of residence permit, the date given to me was June. Due to COVID-19, my date has been shifted by several months and is still slipping down. My original visa was a single entry Visa and so it will expire when I exit. I am now in possession of the Residence Permit receipts and my Single Entry Visa. How do I exit and re-enter Italy to visit home?

Comment: Are you planning to leave after the COVID-19 situation?

Comment: What do you mean by receipts??? In the body of your question you make it sound like you haven't yet applied for the permesso, so what are these receipts you're talking about?

Comment: @Ozzy I think OP applied for residence permit already, but the date of issuance is being pushed down. After they applied, the post office or the police will give them a receipt that's valid to prove temporary status in Italy (but is not a travel document and does not allow re-entry unless it's a renewal receipts). But OP should clarify.

Comment: The receipt is the result of the **Permesso di Soggiorno Kit** and serves as a temporary residence permit. Under the present conditions, you should clarify if a temporary visit home is considered essential travel.

Comment: Under usual circumstances (without COVID-19 restrictions), you need to apply for a permesso di soggiorno provvisorio with justified reasons (you need a reason even without COVID-19) at the local police station. You may get it, you may not get it (work-, or health-related reasons and family emergencies are easier to justify than travel alone).

Answer (score 2):

It was possible in the past to travel with the receipt (*cedolino/tagliandino*) and there were restrictions to do so which I will highlight below;

1. You should have handed in the renewal of your **permit** with the police headquarters (*Questura*) and should be awaiting for your permit which is in process of been issued.
2. You should take a direct flight from an Italian airport to your home country airport without transiting in another Schengen country. (*There are some cases in the past that allowed transit in Schengen countries but communication was issued explicitly by Italy to the other Schengen countries and this was between the months of November and January when Italy had a backlog of permits to process and couldn't cope*)

The best thing I would recommend is go to the *Questura* and ask them because you have not had your first permit of stay yet, which will be based on your expired visa.

After you have a first permit of stay issued, successive permits will not be based on an entry visa but on your previous permit which is issued by the Questura and falls under the jurisdiction of *Ministero dell'interno*. Visa issuance fall under the ministry for foreign affairs (*Ministero degli affari esteri*) and the last thing you want to do is deal with two Italian ministries when you are blocked abroad.